# CURL URL parameters not received by server

Tags: php, curl

I want to grab the full HTML source code with curl/php from a website which has a simple login. I can perform the login process and get the source code, but the server on the other end seems to ignore all the html parameters.

When I run the code provided below I get the source code of this url: https://www.example.com/page and not of https://www.example.com/page?user=1&date=2018-12-12.
If I open the url with the parameters in any web browser it shows the correct website.

I tried to grab another site with parameters from a different server and website which worked perfectly: https://www.example2.com/otherpage?user=1&date=2018-12-12

```
<?php define('USERNAME', 'user');
define('PASSWORD', '1234');
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113
Safari/537.36'); 
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://www.example.com/admin');
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://www.example.com/admin');

$postValues = array(
    'user' => USERNAME,
    'pass' => PASSWORD 
); 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));   

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);   

curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl)); 
}  

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/page?user=1&date=2018-12-12");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

echo curl_exec($curl);

?>
```

Source: http://thisinterestsme.com/php-login-to-website-with-curl/

I am confused because it is working with example2.com but not with example.com (which are of course two different web servers and sites). Any idea?

Comment: One of the servers has maybe another url-signature? Maybe it uses POST, not GET? Maybe it has a .htaccess file and uses clean-urls?

Comment: But how does the server distinguish between my curl request and the url requested in a normal browser?

Comment: it doesn't. And it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount a workaround which is working:

Create a new .php file with this simple line of code:

```
header('Location: https://www.example.com/page?user=1&date=2018-12-12');
```

And in the main .php file just replace the url above with the new .php files url:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "newfile.php");
```